# Do not allow malloc()?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a makefile that builds, runs unit tests, memory leaks etc. But is there a way I can stop malloc(), free(), calloc() and the like from being used in the source code?

I have replacement memory functions that handle things like mocking. Is there a way I can enforce EagleMemory_Free() to be used instead of free(), for example.

My replacement functions have a different signature so I can't simply create a macro that points the internal one to my own:

```
void* EagleMemory_Allocate(char *id, size_t size);
void EagleMemory_Free(void *ptr);
void** EagleMemory_MultiAllocate(char *id, size_t size, int quantity);
void EagleMemory_MultiFree(void **ptr, int quantity);
void EagleMemory_MockInit(void);
void EagleMemory_Mock(char *id);
void EagleMemory_MockFinish(void);
int EagleMemory_GetMockInvocations(void);
```

Oh, I should also point out I don't want to replace the function at runtime and cause my software to crash - that's just stupid. I want to catch the use of the std function at build time or through some other script before the software runs.

Comment: What is your different signature?

Comment: Check this out http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23

Comment: In theory you could either scan the source code or the symbols in the compiled code (or the map file) to see if they're used. If you make this check automatic and mandatory before any new code goes into your source control, you will disallow the use of these functions. Another option to try is to link in fake `malloc/calloc/free` that would print the appropriate error message and terminate the program.

Comment: How do I search the generated symbol files?

Comment: See if there are any tools to dump the contents of object/executable files. `objdump` might be helpful if you're on gcc. Or roll your own parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Alexey Frunze. The `nm` command was exactly what I needed. I added this to my makefile:

```
NM = nm $(OBJS)/*.o -o 2>&1 | grep -v EagleMemory.o | grep -w '_malloc\|_calloc\|_free'

leaks: build_eagle_test
    if [ `$(NM) | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then \
        echo "\n==> Do not use stdlib memory functions, use EagleMemory functions instead. <=="; \
        $(NM); \
        exit 1; \
    fi

    ...
```

Works great!

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution would be to compile everything with:

```
 -Dmalloc=@ERROR -Dfree=@ERROR
```

(and probably likewise for `calloc` and `realloc`).  This won't enforce the replacement of `malloc` by `EagleMemory_Malloc`, but it will cause any call to `malloc` to fail to compile.

(I picked `@ERROR` because it can't occur in legal C source.)

Note that there may still be *indirect* calls to `malloc` and friends; for example, `strdup()`  calls `malloc()`. (`strdup` is not defined by ISO C, but it's defined by POSIX.)

Comment: This was a good idea but the compiler picks up the prototype for malloc() in stdlib.h as an error also :(

Comment: @ElliotChance: Can you insert `#define` directives after the standard header `#include`s? (Probably not, and certainly not cleanly or easily.)

Answer (score 0):

What about defining :

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{ 
    return EagleMemory_Malloc(size);
}
```

and so on...

Edit :

I give you the power of variadic arguments with this brand new version, it may be overkill but your "different signature" deserves the best !

```
#define malloc(...) EagleMemory_Malloc(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Did you read this: `My replacement functions have a different signature so I can't simply create a macro that points the internal one to my own.`

Comment: And this "different signature" is... ?

Comment: Of course you can use a macro. Just use macro parameters: `#define free(x) MyFree(foo, bar, x)`

Comment: `void* EagleMemory_Allocate(char *id, size_t size);`

Comment: Are you sure it's not `const char *id`? Who came up what that idea? Either way, try this: `#define malloc (x) EagleMemory_Allocate(__FILE__##__LINE__, x);` That will supply  the file + line number to EagleMemory.

Comment: The `id` has to be manual. The unit tests that mock memory failures would all stop working every time the line moved.

Answer (score 0):

use macros:

```
#define free EagleMemory_Free
```

Comment: Did you read this: `My replacement functions have a different signature so I can't simply create a macro that points the internal one to my own.`